# whats the difference between associated_token::mint and token::mint in anchor

Tags: anchor, solana-program

can someone please help me understand the difference between
associated_token::mint and token::mint. I've seen both used interchangeably in anchor account contexts when setting constraints for token accounts.

For example:

```
    ...
    nft_mint: Account<'info, Mint>,
    #[account(
        token::mint=nft_mint,
        token::authority=signer
    )]
    nft_token_account: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
```

Or

```
    ...
    nft_mint: Account<'info, Mint>,
    #[account(
        associated_token::mint=nft_mint,
        associated_token::authority=signer
    )]
    nft_token_account: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
```

I've also seen this used too

```
    ...
    nft_mint: Account<'info, Mint>,
    #[account(
        constraint=nft_token_account.owner == signer.key(),
        constraint=nft_token_account.mint == nft_mint.key()
    )]
    nft_token_account: Box<Account<'info, TokenAccount>>,
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tokenaccounts of a publickey that have a corresponding private key are usually Associated Token Accounts(ATA). An ATA is a PDA that uses the publickey and token mint as seeds. However, to generate a token account that is a PDA, you generate the PDA from your custom seeds and then instruct the Token Program to create a token account with your specified token_mint and specified authority.

`associated_token::mint = mint` and `associated_token::authority = signer` enforces that the token account generated uses the specified `mint` and `signer` as seeds alongside enforcing that the token account corresponds to the specified `mint` and the token account authority corresponds to the `signer` while `token::mint = mint` and `token::authority = signer` only enforce that the token account corresponds to the specified `mint` and the token account authority corresponds to the specified `signer`.

Hence, using `associated_token::` would not work for token accounts that are PDAs, `token::` should be used instead. Consequently, this means that multiple token accounts for a publickey that has a private key can be generated but only one of them can be an ATA.

```
    constraint = nft_token_account.owner == signer.key(),
    constraint = nft_token_account.mint == nft_mint.key()
```

These constraints above just check the mint and authority of a token account(works for either PDA or non-PDA token account if the right constraints are passed). The above constraints are an alternative to either using `token::` or `associated_token::` and only work for an already existing token account.

Comment: While trying to answer your question, I discovered something when testing my assumptions, I think you should also check this [out](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/3422/why-is-associatedtoken-program-not-needed-when-using-associated-token-constraint).